# Header wont redirect me, can't figure out why

Tags: php, mysql

i cannot figure out why this will not redirect me or tell me any errors, it adds to the database but it does not redirect

```
<?php
    ob_start();

        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "autentificare");

        if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])){
            session_start();
            $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
            $passwordc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwordc']);

            if ($password == $passwordc){
                    $password = md5($password);
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')" ;
                    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
                    $_SESSION['message'] = "Succesfully logged in";
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    header( "location : home.php");
            }else{
                    $_SESSION['message'] = "Passwords do not match";

            }
        }
    ob_end_flush();
    ?>
```

Comment: Wow, stop reading the outdated tutotrials about _mysql_**i**. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead!

Comment: I can't possibly see this code working. It's not showing you errors because you didn't check for them and you have many.

Comment: *"it adds to the database"* - I find that rather hard to believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending the header, but then letting the script continue to process. Use this:

```
header( "location : home.php");
exit();
```

Comment: I honestly can't see how this will possibly work and why it received upvotes and accepted; did you try it yourself?